# Pulling data from a list in a dataform web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

this might be an overly complicated solution to a problem I face due to somewhat ridiculous business rule restrictions.

I have a sharepoint site that is supposed to be the central repository for forms. So I have those forms in a document Library Only problem is not all the forms sit there, some infopath forms are hosted elsewhere, and some "forms" are actually other web pages. So I have a List set up with the form name, and a column storing the URL of the location of that form (forms in the local library included) however, sharepoint has a RIDICULOUS restriction on URL column types for 255 characters, a single line of text has the same stupid restriction, so I have created the column as a multiple line text field. I need more than 255 characters as some of the infopath forms URL's are rather lengthy.
Now the datasource of the dataform web part is the List. In my aspx page I have the following pulling through what I THOUGHT should be the text which is the URL of the forms location, format that as a hyperlink.

```
<ul><a href="{@FormLocation}" target="_blank">
<xsl:value-of select="@Title" /></a></ul></td>
```

This is the section that pulls through the text and formats it as a hyperlink.
@FormLocation is the column with the text url. @Title is the forms Title.

What happens is that the rendered HTML get's populated with the url that i want but it is PREFIXED with the following.

http://MYSITESSANITISEDURL.za/en/prettysanitary/Documents/%3Cdiv%20class=%22ExternalClassDF5DF9081DE54EECB4500A4E7B5592A1%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ca%20href=%22

Then my required text is placed and it is then suffixed with

```
</a></div></div>
```

The prefix that is put in is actually the location of the page that the webpart is on.

Does anyone have ANY idea WHY

```
<a href="{@FormLocation}" target="_blank">
```

pulls through more than what actually sits in that @FormLocation column?

I am exceptionally new to sharepoint, and 5 of the sharepoint "guru's" here have no idea at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would check XML content of that column using <xsl:copy-of select="*|@*" \> . Then you'll probably need to escaping/noescaping FormLocation display using xsl:attribute with xsl:value-of

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I have to say that I don't understand it. My experience in web and sharepoint is 3 months old. Could you give a more verbose response, with greater detail?

Comment: You show a XSLT fragment between <ul> and </ul> . You could make a test changing that fragment with (without quotes) "XMLEMBEDDED<xsl:copy-of select="\*|@\*" />ENDXMLEMBEDD" . Load page with browser, then look in source of page (right click on page from browser) near XMLEMBEDDED you should find content of your columns before is formatted by XSLT. I suspect your content could be stored as an hypelink